# array[1] doesn't work while array+1 works

Tags: c, pointers

As far as I've understood this far array[1] and array+1 are practically two ways of writing the same thing. However I've been looking at void pointers and arrays recently and made this program to test my understanding of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    void** data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    *((int*)data) = 5;
    *((int*)(data+1)) = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)data));
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)(data+1)));
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

That is the version of the program that works, for some reason however this version doesn't

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    void** data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    *((int*)data[0]) = 5;
    *((int*)data[1]) = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)data));
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)data1]));
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not exactly getting compiler errors but program simply stops running, I've compiled this on a win 10 machine using gcc with the following flags `-pedantic-errors -Wall` and like i said before, the program compiles but when run I get the classic `Program.exe has stopped working` error message and so far I really can't think of a single reason why one of those would work and the other wouldn't.

Comment: No: `array[1]` is the same as `*(a + 1)` — the `*` makes all the difference.

Comment: In your second example, you have: `printf("%d\n", *((int*)data1]));` — there's a missing `[`.

Comment: Why are you using void pointers?

Comment: Do you realize `data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);` is very wrong?

Comment: In your first listing, the expression `data` and `data+1` calculates the first and second `void*` in a sequence; a sequence that doesn't even *exist*, since you allocated two `int`, not two `void*`. You later take those phantom `void**` and dereference them to nowhere. Your first code does **not** "work". If it *appears* to, that's unfortunate, because you would have been better off *not* being lulled into a false sense of correctness.

Comment: What's the point of using a double pointer: `void**`?

Comment: [Here's a nice valgrind dump](http://pastebin.com/dYLKdSaP) of your first code **not** "work"ing.

Comment: @M.M Well, sir, we all know the danger involved. :)

Comment: @jonathanleffler that second part with the printf was a typo sorry about that. I realize my implementation of this is wrong now, i just didn't fully understand void pointers (and some aspects of normal pointers).

Answer (score 2):

`data+1` is not valid C. You cannot do pointer arithmetic on void pointers, since that wouldn't make any sense.

So it would seem that you are using gcc in non-standard crap mode (default setting), which translates void pointer arithmetic to character arithmetic and therefore the program compiles, but as non-standard C. `data+1` would then mean +1 byte, not +1 `int`.

Use gcc as a a standard C compiler instead `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Then change the code to `(int*)data+1`.

Also the `void**` makes no sense, should be a `void*`. Please note that `(int*)data[0]` means "do pointer arithmetic on `void**` type, *then* cast the result to `int*`. This is an operator precedence bug. `[]` has higher precedence than the cast `()` operator.

Just toss that whole code out and use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    void* data;
    data = malloc( sizeof(int[2]) );
    ((int*)data)[0] = 5;
    ((int*)data)[1] = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)data );
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)data+1) );
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `data` is not a void*, it is a void** on which arithmetic is perfectly defined

Comment: ah ok i though -pedantic-errors and -Wall would be enough to stop that. And thank you for letting me know about the operator precedence bug. However the reason I've been using `void **` was honestly because I've been looking at how dynamic arrays are done and I've seen multiple times people saying to use `void **` over `void*`. I'm somewhat confused as to why people would suggest `void **` is there an advantage to using it over just a void pointer?

Comment: @chqrlie Well yeah, the summary is that the original code is strange and doesn't do what the OP thought it would.

Comment: @zee It's because the people suggesting it are confused too. [Info about dynamic multi-dimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are not correct.

```
void** data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

is allocating 2 `int` integers, but `data` if of type `void**`.If you wish to still use this, which is not recommended, you need to allocate 2 `void*` pointers. This would then be:

```
void** data = malloc(sizeof(void*)*2);
```

Having said this, using `void**` is not needed here. You can just use `void*` as pointed out in @Lundin's post. Your code would be optimal if you use `int *data` instead though, as it doesn't really make sense to use `void*` pointers here. If you decide to do this, your code can just be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int *data;
    data = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    data[0] = 5;
    data[1] = 10;
    printf("%d\n", data[0]);
    printf("%d\n", data[1]);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is more straightforward, and skips the complications that `void*` pointers bring in code.

**Note:** You must check return of `malloc()` always, as it can return `NULL` on failure.

Comment: ok thank you, i thought i was supposed to allocate using the sizeof what that pointer was goin to point to. As for using int* im only giving this code as an example so this isn't the way im actually using it, I'm mainly trying to understand pointers and generic pointers as well as how arrays and dynamic arrays work.

Answer (score -2):

**first:** please change the type of `data` to `int*` or at least to `void*`.
don't mess with `void**` unless you need to pass to a function a pointer.

**second:** change `data[0/1]` to `&data[0/1]`.`data[]` is an argument and `&data[]` is his pointer. if you still using the `void*` choose `*((int*)data+?)`. if yopu changed to `int*` use `data[?]`.

**third:** why to use pointers in this function? this is not a function that need pointers.

**fourth:** i would suggest in this case to use an array instead of the pointers. if you already know the type and size of your argument so you better use arrays. more comfortable.

Comment: Could you please explain WHY he has to do these things?